# Lucene.net - How do I extract small snippets of texts from each match?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

http://quranx.com/Search?q=oh+people+of+heaven&context=Quran

Could anyone tell me how I would change the following code to show snippets of text for each match result?  I've tried reading through examples etc but can only find relevant information for a newer version of Lucene for Java.  Lucene seems to be something of a black box of magic to me.

```c#
public static IEnumerable<SearchResult> Search(
    string queryString, 
    out int totalResults,
    int maxResults = 100)
{
    totalResults = 0;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString))
        return new List<SearchResult>();

    var query = new MultiFieldQueryParser(
        Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30,
        new string[] { "Body", "SecondaryReferences" },
        Analyzer
    ).Parse(queryString);

    var indexReader = DirectoryReader.Open(
        directory: Index,
        readOnly: true);
    var indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
    var resultsCollector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(
        numHits: maxResults,
        docsScoredInOrder: true
    );
    indexSearcher.Search(
        query: query,
        results: resultsCollector
    );
    totalResults = resultsCollector.TotalHits;
    var result = new List<SearchResult>();
    foreach (var scoreDoc in resultsCollector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs)
    {
        var snippets = new List<SearchResultSnippet>();
        var doc = indexSearcher.Doc(scoreDoc.Doc);
        var searchResult = new SearchResult(
            type: doc.Get("Type"),
            id: doc.Get("ID"),
            snippets: snippets
        );
        result.Add(searchResult);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You need [FastVectorHighlighter](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/da/dbb/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_vectorhighlight_1_1_fast_vector_highlighter.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to access the text adjacent to the match, you will need to store TermVectors with position and offset information at indexing time, which you can then use to retrieve the surrounding words.

See http://searchhub.org/2009/05/26/accessing-words-around-a-positional-match-in-lucene/ for a detailed explanation.

Comment: The link no longer loads. I don't suppose you'd have an alternate link?

Comment: As far as I can tell, that link is dead, and the replacement goes to a page that has been removed from the lucidworks site.  _However_, there what appears to be an updated version (from 2013 instead of 2009), posted here: https://lucidworks.com/post/update-accessing-words-around-a-positional-match-in-lucene-4/